# troubling with slick slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I'm trying to customize the styling of the slider pagination dots and when I follow the instruction I found on web, I had to created a list named slick-dots.  But when I created a `ul` element, there is a clone `li` was created too. For example, I had 4 pictures for the slide, so it had to have 4 `li` for the slide, but when I created the `ul` element, there is 5 `li` was created.

How can I avoid or delete the last one?

My HTML code:

```
    <section class="slide-show">
        <div><img src="./style/img/slide1.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./style/img/slide2.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./style/img/slide3.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="./style/img/slide4.jpeg" alt=""></div> 
        <ul class="slick-dots">
            <li role="presentation"></li>
            <li role="presentation"></li>
            <li role="presentation"></li>
            <li role="presentation"></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

and the CSS

```
.slick-dots{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    float: right;
    right: -97%;
}
.slick-dots li{
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example

Comment: i see 4 `li` here

Comment: yes, i only created 4 li and there is only 4 div on the slide but when i check the result, there is 5 slide was created and the last one is empty. i was delete 4 li in the ul element but nothing happen